# Can I use SEC (2/2/2/4 copper) for going from meter to panel

Tags: socket, meter

I am going thru overhead to underground service conversion. For this purpose I need to move the meter to connect with 3” riser. The meter socket would have main disconnect as well.

I am looking at easiest way to do this. I have drawn a picture of possible layout with 2” PvC. But then I read that SEC can be installed outside without a conduit. If that’s the case, I can replace the 2” conduit shown with exposed run of SEC cable going thru wall to panel.

[image: Proposed layout]

Comment: What will the new service capacity be - 200A? What will be the capacity of the panel inside?

Comment: What's your area's adopted code version? Unless they edited that out before adopting, any place on 2020 or later there should be an outside shutoff (most easily done via a meter main when replacing the meter anyway) which I don't see in your drawing. Makes all future inside work very easy since you can shut the power that goes inside all the way off. Also useful for the fire department when needed...

Comment: @Ecnerwal OP stated: *The meter socket would have main disconnect as well.*

Comment: ...why are you using copper for this? O.o

Comment: The current and new capacity are both 200 amp. The meter socket I am planning comes with a disconnect switch. The reason for using copper was as it’s a short run and it comes in a protective sleeves and that’s why I asked the question if it can run over the wall without conduit. If I run inside a conduit, I will use 4/0 AL.

Comment: @Ashterisk -- for a 200A service, you need 2/0 in Cu instead of 2AWG